# Helm template for k8s PodSecurityPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm having a `PodSecurityPolicy` in my Helm Charts and would like to dynamically change the `rule` on `runAsUser`.

When  `{{- if .Values.global.psp.enabled }}` is enabled and the respectrive `values.yaml` contains something like:

```
runAsUnprivilegedUser: true
```

I'm expecting the templates to be rendered like that:

```
runAsUser:
    # Require the container to run without root privileges.
    rule: 'MustRunAsNonRoot'
```

and **additionally** providing a default non-root user with say `UID` 1000.

If, on the other hand, `runAsUnprivilegedUser` is set to `false`, I'd like to have

```
runAsUser:
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
```

employed.

Comment: That seems reasonable; what have you tried so far and what problems are you encountering?

Comment: @DavidMaze, thx. Acutally I'm pretty stuck about how to do the conditional branching and in particular about how to have the default of the non-root user being enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that with conditional statement

```
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: allow-flex-volumes
spec:
  runAsUser:
    # Require the container to run without root privileges.
    {{- if and .Values.global.psp .Values.podSecurityContext}}
    rule: 'MustRunAsNonRoot'
    {{else }}
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
    {{end}}
```

Comment: thx, @hoque. Can I addiationaly employ a default non-root `UID` when `MustRunAsNonRoot` is employed, e. g. like `rule MustRunAsNonRoot | default runAsUser: 1000` ?

Comment: can you check it with ```ranges:
    - max: 1000
      min: 1000``` ? I don't see any other field to provide it directly.